# Finding a Find a nonnegative definite symmetric matrix A such that $A^2 = D$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was tasked with finding a nonnegative definite symmetric matrix such that $A^2=D$ where $D = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Clearly the matrix is diagonalizable but I do not understand how I can use that to find that matrix $A$

Comment: Diagonalize, replace the diagonal by its square root, undiagonalize

Comment: If $D=Q\Lambda Q^T$ is an orthogonal diagonalisation, then $A=Q\sqrt{\Lambda} Q^T$ where $\sqrt{D}$ is the entrywise square root of $\Lambda$.

Comment: There is no such matrix because $D$ fails to be non-negative definite.

Comment: Note for instance that with $v = [3,-4,2]^T$, we have $v^TDv = -3 < 0$

Comment: $Det(D)=-1$ so $A$ must be complex.

Comment: Maybe they mistyped; placing $4$ in the bottom right position would have worked.